# Differentiation - simple case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In the book calculus made easy, page 22 the case of the negative power for

$y=x^{-2}$

---

$$\begin{align} 
y+dy & =(x+dx)^{-2}\tag{1}\\ \\
& = x^{-2}\left(1+\frac{dx}{x}\right)^{-2}\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

How do they get from $(1)$ to $(2)$?

And why isn't the binomial function applied to the second line but applied on the third line (the line that comes after line $(2))$?

Comment: Welcome on this forum, I tried to edit, is this what you want?

Comment: The power on the first two line is supposed to be negative 2, I have managed to fix it - thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, within the parentheses, we factor out an $x$. Then we take each factor within the outer parentheses and raise it to the $(-2)^\text{th}$ power (using the fact that $(ab)^k = a^kb^k$): $$ (x + dx)^{-2} = \left(x\left(1+\frac{\mathrm dx}x\right)\right)^{-2}= x^{-2}\left(1 + \frac{dx}x\right)^{-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$(x+\mathrm dx)^{-2}=\left(x\left(\frac xx+\frac{\mathrm dx}x\right)\right)^{-2}=\ldots$$

Comment: $$\left(x\left(\frac1x+\frac{\mathrm dx}x\right)\right)^{-2}= (1 + dx)^{-2}\neq (x + dx)^{-2}$$

Comment: Why can the binomial function not have been applied to $(x+dx)^{-2}$ directly? Is it not in the form $(a+b)^n$? @amwhy

Comment: @Gert You could apply it. But it looks like your solution manual took a different route.

Comment: Thank you, it is now clear to me what was done and why! @amwhy

Comment: You're welcome, Gert!

Comment: You're welcome, Hakim!